# Ruby String Object Empty or Not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have a string that is the output of Ruby on Rails `render_to_string`

When in the Ruby debugger this is what I get

```
pp string.inspect # ->  blank
pp string         # ->  blank
pp string.Class   # ->  String
pp string.empty?  # ->  false
pp string.nil?    # ->  false
pp string.blank?  # ->  false
pp string.to_s    # ->  blank
```

I know there is content in the string because `logger.info string` returns the string as expected, but I don't know how to get to it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: I figured out that this problem is very localized. It only happens when I am using the ruby-debugger. And it happens to any string that has a percent symbol in it.

For example, If I made a string

```
string = 'this is a string with a % symbol'
```

the string can no longer be inspected, printed, or even unpack.

I am on Ruby 1.8 and Rails 2.3.

I think this may be just part of my lack of understanding about something mundane in Ruby.

Comment: Probably contains a newline character. What does `string.length` give you? Also try `print "["+string+"]"` .. that should also help "see" what the string contains. Try using something other than `pp`, such as `p`,`puts` or `print`.

Comment: string.length returns 12045. It's a long string. The other stuff did not work.

Comment: string.encoding -- Doesn't seem to have that method http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html

Comment: Try defining your own `String.to_s` and `String.to_str` methods : maybe some code is overwriting those and thus no output from the `p`-type methods. Also try `p string.display`. Also try [unpack](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-unpack)ing the string into a binary array and print that and see what you get.

Comment: Can you try `pp string.strip`. Perhaps you have a lot of leading spaces.

Comment: No `encoding` method implies Ruby 1.8. You could try building a quick histogram with `hist = s.chars.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,c| h[c] += 1; h }` and then see if you have any strange looking characters in there.

Comment: Since the string is not empty, try `s.to_sym` and see what that returns.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I have a lot to learn about Strings. I just discovered that when I try to get a substring `string[0,100]` it will return blank once it hits the first percent sign. It will also stop unpacking once it hits the percent sign. Any tips?

Comment: Ok. I don't really know how to explain this. In my irb I can make strings with percent signs just fine. In my script/console for the rails app I am playing with, I can do strings with percent signs just fine. But in the ruby debug for that same app, I can not create a string with a percent sign. Well, actually, I can create it. I just can't read it for inspect it or unpack it.

Comment: Why not just put these as answers to the question?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your string is definitely not  empty.

Can you download the hexdump extension for class String, and do this:

```
require 'hexdump'

#... whatever you do in your program

puts string.hexdump
```

and post the output in your question?

This way we can see what's in the string, even if those are non-printable characters..

See:

http://www.unixgods.org/~tilo/Ruby/hexdump.html